Compact support vs zero outside bounded set
In Advanced Calculus by Loomis and Sternberg, regarding functions $f : \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, they frequently employ the condition that $f$ “has compact support”, where the support of $f$ is defined as

by supp $f$, we shall mean the closure of the set where $f$ is not zero

After thinking a bit about the implications of this “$f$ has compact support” criterion, it occurred to me that this looks like just an overly complicated way of saying that $f$ is zero outside some bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$
Is this right, or am I missing something? For functions $f : \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, is “$f$ has compact support” in fact equivalent to “$\{\mathbf{x}: f(\mathbf{x}) \neq 0 \}$ is bounded”?

You're right, they're equivalent if the domain is $\Bbb R^n$. Not quite if, for instance, the domain is $(0,1)$ or $(0,\infty)$.

As @SassatelliGiulio hinted at, talking about compact support instead of bounded support is useful, since boundedness depends on the metric, but compactness only on the topology. Thus having compact support is invariant under precomposing with a homeomorphism.

Have you seen the Heine-Borel theorem?
